# Using value of propertie in his own custom attribute

Tags: c#, .net, properties, attributes

We use some DTOs in your business logic. I also use these DTOs for printing. So there is a custom attribute `printable` which will be used in the print-framework to recognize which properties to print. In some cases it is necessary to preformat the value for the printengine.
My idea was to use a construct like this:

```
[Printable(formatedValue = DoFormatingXY(MyProperty))]
public int MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

But unfortunatly this will not work (apart from the fact that it is unpleasant to have to use the propertie-name again):

```
Error   An object reference is required for 
        the non-static field, method, or property '...MyPropertie.get'
```

So I understand what the problem is, but how can handle it? One idea was to use delegates, but there are a lot of formatting-methods with different method signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are just metadata, not code. So change it to something like:

```
[Printable(FormatStyle = FormatStyles.XY)]
public int MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

Then the printer code can check for a FormatStyle parameter to the attribute and apply the requested format to the property.

Comment: FormatStyle is some kind of an enum? if yes: then create a switch-case to map form the enum to concrete method for formatting? Is that what you thinking of?

Comment: @Micha, yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say :)

Comment: @Micha, though I'd use a `Dictionary<FormatStyles, Func<...>>` to do the lookup, rather than switch statement, but that's a personal choice.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Indeed helpful -> +1 for that. If there will nothing better I will accept you answer as solution of the question.

Comment: I have tried your recommentation in my code. Works well. Thanks.